# How do I configure Open Rasta to show a webpage under site root

Tags: asp.net, rest, iis-6, openrasta

I am using Open Rasta 2.0 under IIS 6. I would like to redirect the root of the site to a web page.

The [documentation](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta-stable/wiki/Installing-OpenRasta-Under-IIS) says:

> Note that this will disable IIS default page mapping. The work-around
>   is to either expose your default pages using OpenRasta itself....

I cannot work out how to achieve this. I have tried various routes in the configuration but they don't seem to work with IIS. I am also using Cassini server on my DEV pc, it has no issues when no routes are added but under some routes I tried broke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to show a webpage using OpenRasta on the root of the site? In this case you can do something like this when you have [wildcard mappings setup.](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2007/07/27/Configure-IIS-for-Wildcard-Extensions-in-ASP.NET.aspx)

```
using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
{
     ResourceSpace.Has.
     ResourcesOfType<Home>().
     AtUri("/").
     HandledBy<HomeHandler>().
     RenderedByAspx("/views/index.aspx")
}
```

Also when you say routes are you talking about OpenRasta resource configuration or IIS handler mappings?

Comment: I am using OpenRasta resource configuration and all sub pages are rendering .aspx fine, it is just the root. I have re-added the route you have shown however it does not work and then stops all aspx pages from showing. I will check the wildcard mapping to see if that was the issue.

Comment: It was the wildcard mapping that was not configured correctly - thanks